# Trigger bandwidth usage increase gradually by percentage with bash shell and python

Tags: bash, shell-script, python, bandwidth

I have a case monitoring bandwidth and trigger alert Telegram when network traffic increase 200% .

My idea:
Using vnStat print out traffic current , after 5 minutes print out traffic the second time .
From there get 2 data compare increase , if increase 200% then alerting .

I'll show an example :

24h00 => Bandwidth used : 1 Tbps

24h05 => Bandwidth used : 3 Tbps

=> 1 Tbps (after 5 minutes) * 2 (trigger) = 2 Tpbs < 3 Tbps (24h05 current) then alerting .

P/s: I need more support ideas. Thank for the other ideas.

Comment: so first i read some stuff on a website that uses 400 KB. 5 minutes later i watch a video tutorial that uses 30 MB. time for alert?

Comment: Exactly . But for me it would be Gbps, Tbps .

Comment: your idea needs continuously minimum Gbps as requirement at every second of time. maybe i wasn't clear with my example. i will try again: first i read a website that is already in cache, that uses 0 KB (at time of measurement, but lets say 1 KB for calculation). 5 minutes later i reload the page that uses 400 KB. percentage over that two current values makes absolutely no sense for monitoring without any relation to reference value (maximum bandwidth)

Comment: I'll show you an example :
24h00 => Bandwidth used : 1 Tbps
|
24h05 => Bandwidth used : 3 Tbps
|
=> 1 Tbps (after 5 minutes) * 2 (trigger) = 2  Tpbs < 3 Tbps (24h05 current) then alerting .

Comment: yes i am not stupid but that does need continuously minimum 1 Tbps (terrabits per second) as requirement. if you can't guarantee that continuously (stable) traffic, a single gap of lets say it drops down to 1 Mbps for just a millisecond, if you accidentially catch exactly this low value at time of measurement, your calculation is senseless